# Forum plugin that allows private groups that are invite only

Tags: plugins, private, forum

I'm looking for a plugin that would allow me to create private groups for discussion that are invite only.  These would be for people who have taken a workshop and want to remain in communication with their cohort afterwards.  They would need to be invited/added by admin after each workshop and would not communicate with other participants. Anyone have any ideas?  Appreciate the help!

Comment: So they need to be able to talk to certain people but not others?

Comment: Right, just folks within their group - people who took the same workshop as them.  But there will be multiple workshops so there needs to be multiple private groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create private forums with the Simple:Press forum plugin.

http://simple-press.com/

It can do a LOT more than just that, and for that reason might be overkill (not sure what other requirements you have), but if you are looking for a very flexible and powerful forum system, then I can recommend Simple:Press.

Answer (score 1):

BuddyPress is good for this as well. You can create public, private or hidden groups and control who can invite others.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress/
You have the option to have forums in each of the groups as well.